# Pro Evolution Soccer 2013 won't work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, pro-evolution-soccer-2013

I'm trying to run Pro Evolution Soccer 2013 on my Windows 8 laptop, but the game won't even start. It runs fine on Windows 7 however.

My laptop is a *Dell XPS 15 (L502X)* with a Nvidia GT540M and Intel HD3000 in Nvidia Optimus.

I have tried

- Running the game in compatibility mode, and
- Configuring the game in the Nvidia control panel

but I haven't had any success.

Comment: according to this link, it should work: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=Pro%20Evolution%20Soccer%202013&vendor=Konami%20Digital%20Entertainment&Locale=1033&ModelOrVersion=1&BreadCrumbPath=Pro%20Evolution%20Soccer%202013&Type=Software&tempOsid=win8 Have you installed all requirements (C++ Runtime,s DirectX9)?

Comment: Yes yes, I have ALL requirements. But I solve problem using crack (Yes, original game with crack), BUTTTT, I realized that in windows 8, rdl.dll the file is not copied, and I think the lack of it is causing the problem. But nenhuma mensagem não aparecendo estava lack accusing give.